# Briefcases open slowly in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Why do Briefcases on the desktop take about 5 minutes to open.  A regular folder of comparable size opens fast.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a known issue since Windows Vista. It is a bug. There seems to be no remedy except to just not use the briefcase.